# I am now faced with repeated terminal problems. plz

Tags: flutter, macos, shell, terminal, cocoapods

I have a repeated terminal problem.

If i turn on the terminal and run the flutter doctor, it says command not found and it does not work.

So if i type [export PATH="$PATH:`pwd`/flutter/bin"] and enter the flutter doctor, it is worked

In addition, the flutter doctor was executed like this, but the version of cocoapods was low, causing continuous errors.

and then, i typeed [source ~/.zshrc] and [sudo gem install cocoapods]

I entered these and they work normally.

But I wonder if I have to go through these procedures every time I turn on the terminal.

I don't think this problem is a problem for me to run the flutter in vscode.

Can't I save the procedure I enter so that I don't find any errors when I run the flutter doctor right from the terminal?

If I can't do that, is there no problem using flutter in vscode even if I keep the current situation?

thank u

1. type [export PATH="$PATH:`pwd`/flutter/bin"]
2. type [source ~/.zshrc] and [sudo gem install cocoapods]

Answer (score 0):

Try to do this:

- Type: `open ~/.zshrc`
- Edit inside your zshrc: `PATH="$PATH:$HOME/development/flutter/bin"`. Well in my case, the flutter folder is in `$HOME/development`, replace this in your corresponding path.
- Delete all of redundant other `flutter/bin` in zshrc.
- Close your text edit & run `source ~/.zshrc`.
- Exit your current terminal. If you are in vscode, close your terminal & exit vscode also.

Comment: Hi, your reply was very helpful to me. Thank you, but I have one more question. In order to execute the flutter doctor to check these changes, the change of zshrc must be saved in the source command in the terminal to properly execute the flutter doctor. Is there no way to save changes to this either?

Answer (score 0):

My problem was that I didn't create a development folder at home. Creating and re-downloading the development folder resolved most issues.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).